# Validity of proof extended Riemann zeta function based on $\eta(s)$ has only 1 pole.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

It is well known the common Riemann Zeta series $\sum 1/n^s$, converges for $\sigma>1$ where $s=\sigma+it$.

The following series extends the domain to be convergent over $\sigma>0$.

$$\boxed{\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{s}}}$$

**Aim: I want to prove this has only 1 pole at $s=1$.**

---

**My Argument**

The alternating zeta function, also known as the eta $\eta(s)$ function is as follows:

$$\eta(s)=\sum\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{s}}=1-\frac{1}{2^{s}}+\frac{1}{3^{s}}-\frac{1}{4^{s}}+\frac{1}{5^{s}}-\ldots$$

Dirichlet theory (eg Apostol's IANT) allows us to observe that because $\sum (-1)^{n+1}$ is bounded, the series converges for $\sigma>0$ where $s=\sigma+it$.

That means $\eta(s)$ has no poles in the domain $\sigma>0$ and therefore the above $\zeta(s)$ must get any poles from the factor $1/(1-2^{1-s})$.

That factor diverges when $1-s=0$, which means $s=1$. Therefore the above $\zeta(s)$ has only one pole at $s=1$.

---

**Question: Is this argument correct and sufficient?**

Comment: The factor $1/(1-2^{1-s})$ also has a pole for $1-s=2\pi i n/\log 2$, $n\in\Bbb Z$, so you will need to show that they cancel out for $n\ne0$

Comment: @leoli1 by cancel out, do you mean that the eta series $\eta(s)$ has zeros at exactly $s=1-2\pi i n/\log 2$? is this easy to do?

Comment: There is a direct way to do it, see the article linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991498/riemann-zeta-function-at-s-1-2-pi-i-n-ln-2?rq=1). Alternatively, maybe a bit easier, you can show $\zeta(s)=1/(1-3^{1-s})\cdot(\dots)$, where $(\dots)$ is a in $\sigma>0$ convergent series similar to the $\eta$-function. The only possible poles of this will occur when $1-s=2\pi im/\log 3$, now when can it happen that $2\pi im/\log 3=2\pi i n/\log 2$?

Comment: @leoli1 - I was working through your suggestion today with a pen and paper. If I've understood it correctly, it is indeed a clever suggestion. I'd like to check I have understood. The series would be $X(s) = 1/1^s + 1/2^s - 2/3^s + 1/4^s + 1/5^s - 2/6^s + ... $. This leads to your expression for $\zeta(s)=1/(1-3^{1-s})\cdot X(s)$. Now we have two expressions for $\zeta(s)$ which must be equal, and so $2\pi im/\log 3=2\pi i n/\log 2$. This is only possible for $m=n=0$, so we have shown that there is only one pole at $s=1$, and by implication $X(s)$ has zeros at the other poles to cancel them.

Comment: And the reason $m=n=0$ is because $m$ and $n$ are integers but $m/n=\log 3 / \log 2$ is irrational ... is this correct?

Comment: Also interesting is that we can use the same method to develop series $\zeta(s)=1/(1-N^{1-s})\cdot X(s)$ for any natural number $N$.

Comment: I have asked this question as a proper question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237638/proof-riemann-zeta-series-based-on-etas-has-only-one-pole

Comment: Looks right to me

Comment: hi @leoli1 there's a pushback at the other question on this proof, which I don't understand .. do you have a view? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237638/proof-riemann-zeta-series-based-on-etas-has-only-one-pole from user Steven Clark