# Proof Riemann Zeta Series based on $\eta(s)$ has only one pole.

Tags: convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

This proof is my understanding of a very interesting comment by @leoli1 on my previous related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4235463/validity-of-proof-extended-riemann-zeta-function-based-on-etas-has-only-1-p) about the following extended Riemann Zeta function which converges for $\sigma>0$ where $s=\sigma+it$.

$$\boxed{\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{s}}}$$

**Question: Is my proof a correct understanding of @leoli1's suggestion?**

---

**Step 1**

We find yet another series for $\zeta(s)$ using the following series:

$$ X(s)= \frac{1}{1^s} + \frac{1}{2^s} - \frac{2}{3^s} + \frac{1}{4^s} + \frac{1}{5^s} - \frac{2}{6^s} + \ldots$$

Then

$$\begin{align} \zeta(s) - X(s) &= \frac{3}{3^s} + \frac{3}{6^s} + \frac{3}{6^s} + \ldots \\ \\ &= \frac{3}{3^s} \zeta(s) \end{align} $$

Rearranging gives us

$$ \boxed{\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1-3^{1-s}} X(s) }$$

---

**Step 2**

We observe that $\sum(-1)^{n+1}/n^{s}$ is a Dirichlet series that converges for $\sigma>0$. Therefore it has no poles $\sigma>0$.

Similarly we observe that $X(s)$ is a Dirichlet series that converges for $\sigma>0$, because the sum of the coefficients $1+1-2+1+1-2 + \ldots$ is bounded. Therefore it has no poles $\sigma>0$.

This means any poles must come from the factors $(1-2^{1-s})^{-1}$ and $(1-3^{1-s})^{-1}$.

---

**Step 3**

The factors have poles at $s$ where

$$ 1- s = 2i\pi n \;/ \;\ln(2)$$

and

$$ 1-s = 2i\pi m \;/ \;\ln(3) $$

Where $n$ and $m$ are integers. However

$$ \frac{n}{m} = \frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(3)} $$

The RHS is irrational, and therefore only $n=m=0$ satisfies the expression.

---

**Step 4**

Therefore $\zeta(s)$ has only one pole, at $s=1$, corresponding to $n=m=0$.

---

**Remark:** If correct, this seems a very powerful way of showing the zeros of the sums $\sum(-1)^{n+1}/n^{s}$ and $X(s)$ cancel exactly the poles of the factors $(1-2^{1-s})^{-1}$ and $(1-3^{1-s})^{-1}$. **Is this correct?**

---

Comment: I don't see how introducing a second formula proves anything about the first formula. I believe $\zeta (s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\eta (s)$ has removable singularities at $s=1+\frac{2 i \pi  k}{\log (2)}$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}\land k\ne 0$: $\zeta\left(1+\frac{2 i \pi k}{\log(2)}\right)=\underset{s\to 1+\frac{2 i \pi k}{\log(2)}}{\text{lim}}\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\eta(s)$. It seems to me your question switches gears from proving something about the initial formula for $\zeta(s)$ to proving something about $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: hi @StevenClark the two formulae must be equal as they both represent $\zeta(s)$ so what is true for one must be true for the other. Let me know if I'm mistaken (I'm not mathematically trained at university level)

Comment: hi @conrad I wonder if this question is of interest to you?

Comment: @StevenClark The fact that $s=1+2i\pi k/\log(2)$ for $k\ne0$ are *removable* singularities of $(1-2^{1-s})^{-1}\eta(s)$ is exactly what is being shown here. Introducing the other formula shows that the only possible points for non-removable singularities are $1+2\pi i m/\log(3)$. But the first formula shows that these are removable for $m\ne0$ (because $\log(2)/\log(3)$ is irrational as OP argued).

Comment: Thanks both @StevenClark and leoli1 .. I am self-teaching maths and both your contributions have helped me think deeper about this.

Comment: @leoli1 I think it depends on what's being assumed to be known both about $\zeta(s)$ and the first formula for $\zeta(s)$ which isn't totally clear to me from the question. If the assumptions are it's known that $\zeta(s)$ is continuous everywhere except at $s=1$ and the first formula converges to $\zeta(s)$ for $\Re(s)>0\land s\ne1+\frac{2 i \pi  k}{\log (2)}$, then it seems to me you don't need a second formula to convince yourself that the first formula converges to $\zeta(s)$ in a limit sense at $s=1+\frac{2 i \pi  k}{\log(2)}\land k\ne 0$.

Comment: @StevenClark - the starting assumptions are that the series $\sum 1/n^s$ is known to converge for $\sigma>1$ and has a singularity at $s=1$. When extended using the alternating $\eta(s)$ series, it is not immediately known whether there is only 1 pole. We know the $\eta(s)$ series converges for $\sigma>0$ but the fraction factor $(1-2^{1-s})^{-1}$ could introduce poles unless they are removed by zeros of $\eta(s)$. I think this proof by Leoli1 is a neat way to show they are all removed. Again - do tell me if I've made a mistake in this logic.

Comment: The assumptions weren't clear to me and also whether you were trying to prove something about $\zeta(s)$ or about a formula for $\zeta(s)$, but I don't see a problem with the logic.

Comment: hi @leoli1 - I've run into a potential niggle. If I use a Dirichlet series $Y(s)=1+ 1/2^s + 1/3^s - 3/4 +\ldots$ we end up with $\zeta(s) = (1-4^{1-s})^{-1} Y(s)$. This leads to poles at $s=1 + 2\pi i K/ \log(4)$ ... and since $\ln(4)=2\log(2)$ this leads to $M/K=1/2$ which isn't irrational. This seems to break the original logic. I've been struggling for 24hours with this. I wonder if you can reassure/help?

Comment: Yes, if we only consider $(1-4^{1-s})\zeta(s)$ and $(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$ this will not be enough to conclude that $\zeta(s)$ has no poles other than $1$. That's why we also consider $(1-3^{1-s})\zeta(s)$

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance @leoli1 - I will think more about this to see if I can crack it. By the way I would like to write this up on my blog and the associated YouTube - how would you like to be credited? Simply LeoLi1? https://fromprimestoriemann.blogspot.com